# How to get the token of record programmatically in Odoo 13

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-13, email-templates

I am using this in a mail template in my custom module, the token and action in URL go empty, I don't understand why. is there a mistake in my syntax "token=${object.access_token}"?, "action=${'action_id' in ctx and ctx['action_id'] or ''}".

**Here's the hyperlink from mail : "[Approve](/leave/validate?res_id=$%7Bobject.id%7D&token=$%7Bobject.access_token%7D&action=$%7B%27action_id%27%20in%20ctx%20and%20ctx[%27action_id%27]%20or%20%27%27%7D%20)"**

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check what type of body_html you need to use,

```
<field name="body_html" type="html">
```

You have to use above type to access the object varible along with **{}**.

can you check again with the same?

Thanks

Comment: Thankyou for your reply sir, but i didn't understood what you are trying to say. are you telling me to check into the core XML to view the name of the field and then use object.name to get it?. but I think for token it is a different case  and we have to use access_token method, please correct me If i am wrong.

Comment: is ${object.access_token} valid in Odoo 13?

Comment: Check the file for reference: /odoo-13.0/addons/calendar/data/mail_data.xml, in this access_token is used in <a> link.